# Scale/resize a symbol in Sketch?

Tags: sketch-app, symbols

when I use Sketch 3.8.3 and I still can't scale/resize a symbol.
There is any ways or tricks to do it ?

When I create an symbol of a logo for exemple and use it in différent pages and I want to use it in different size. By this, if one day I change the logo, I only need ti change once and it will change it everywhere. If I need to make one symbol for each size of the logo, it will be less confortable :)

Thx ;)

Comment: [None of these](http://www.google.com/search?q=scale+symbol+sketch) answer your question? Could you tell us what you tried that didn't work? Always good to show some effort, and your chances for a good answer increase. If you have any questions, please see the [help] or ping one of us in the [chat] once your reputation is sufficient (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

Comment: Sorry, I was thinking that it will be enough because I see others questions like mine with more details but the real question is the scale resize of symbol individually. I'll tried to make better next time, all my apologizes ;)

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a look at [Compo](https://evilmartians.com/chronicles/compo-sketch), which is a plugin that makes dynamic resizable UI components, kind of a replacement for symbols.

Answer (score 0):

Sketch 39 just introduced this feature. You can even specify how each element behaves when the symbol is resized.